# Wrong Operator Overloading, CRTP, C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, parentheses, crtp

I am using [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) for operator overloading. I have the **base struct**.

```
template<int S, typename T, typename C>
struct ColorModel {
    constexpr static int SPACE = S;

    ColorModel() {
        std::fill(begin(), end(), 0);
    }

    ColorModel(const ColorModel& another) {
        std::copy(another.begin(), another.end(), begin());
    }

    ColorModel(ColorModel&& another) noexcept {
        std::move(another.begin(), another.end(), begin());
    }

    ColorModel(const std::initializer_list<T>& l) {
        std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), begin());
    }

    explicit ColorModel(const T& elem) {
        std::fill(begin(), end(), elem);
    }

    constexpr inline const T* cbegin() const {
        return static_cast<const C*>(this)->components.cbegin();
    }

    constexpr inline const T* cend() const {
        return static_cast<const C*>(this)->components.cend();
    }

    constexpr inline const T* begin() const {
        return cbegin();
    }

    constexpr inline const T* end() const {
        return cend();
    }

    constexpr inline T* begin() {
        return static_cast<C*>(this)->components.begin();
    }

    constexpr inline T* end() {
        return static_cast<C*>(this)->components.end();
    }

    constexpr inline size_t size() const {
        return std::distance(begin(), end());
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator=(const ColorModel& rhs) {
        std::copy(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), begin());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator=(ColorModel&& rhs) noexcept {
        std::move(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), begin());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator=(const T& rhs) {
        std::fill(begin(), end(), rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator=(T&& rhs) {
        std::fill(begin(), end(), rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator+=(const ColorModel& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::plus<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator+=(ColorModel&& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::plus<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator+=(const T& rhs) {
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, begin(), std::plus<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator+=(T&& rhs) {
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, begin(), std::plus<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator-=(const ColorModel& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::minus<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator-=(ColorModel&& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::minus<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator-=(const T& rhs) {
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, begin(), std::minus<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator-=(T&& rhs) {
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, begin(), std::minus<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator*=(const ColorModel& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator*=(ColorModel&& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator*=(const T& rhs) {
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator*=(T&& rhs) {
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator/=(const ColorModel& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::divides<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator/=(ColorModel&& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::divides<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator/=(const T& rhs) {
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, begin(), std::divides<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator/=(T&& rhs) {
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, begin(), std::divides<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel operator+(const ColorModel& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), result.begin(), std::plus<>());
        return result;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel operator+(ColorModel&& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), result.begin(), std::plus<>());
        return result;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel operator+(const T& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, result.begin(), std::plus<>());
        return result;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel operator+(T&& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, result.begin(), std::plus<>());
        return result;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel operator-(const ColorModel& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), result.begin(), std::minus<>());
        return result;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel operator-(ColorModel&& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), result.begin(), std::minus<>());
        return result;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel operator-(const T& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, result.begin(), std::minus<>());
        return result;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel operator-(T&& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, result.begin(), std::minus<>());
        return result;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel operator*(const ColorModel& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), result.begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return result;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel operator*(ColorModel&& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), result.begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return result;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel operator*(const T& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, result.begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return result;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel operator*(T&& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, result.begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return result;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel operator/(const ColorModel& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), result.begin(), std::divides<>());
        return result;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel operator/(ColorModel&& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), result.begin(), std::divides<>());
        return result;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel operator/(const T& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, result.begin(), std::divides<>());
        return result;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel operator/(T&& rhs) const {
        ColorModel result;
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, result.begin(), std::divides<>());
        return result;
    }
};

template<int S, typename T, typename C>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ColorModel<S, T, C>& model) {
    for (const auto& elem : model) {
        os << elem << " ";
    }
    return os;
}
```

And this is the *child* of base struct

```
struct RGB : ColorModel<0, int, RGB> {
    std::array<int, 3> components;

    RGB() : ColorModel() {

    }

    RGB(const RGB& other) : ColorModel(other) {

    }

    RGB(RGB&& other) : ColorModel(other) {

    }

    RGB(const std::initializer_list<int>& l) : ColorModel(l) {

    }

    explicit RGB(const int& elem) : ColorModel(elem) {

    }

    using ColorModel<0, int, RGB>::operator=;
};
```

**Here is the code of my `util::transform` function**

```
namespace util {
    template<typename Iterator, typename T, typename BinaryOperator>
    void transform(Iterator begin, Iterator end, const T& elem, Iterator result, BinaryOperator anOperator) {
        for (; begin != end; ++begin, ++result) {
            *result = anOperator(*begin, elem);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I started testing it out in `main.cpp` I've got weird results.

```
int main() {
    RGB rgb1{1, 2, 3};
    RGB rgb2{2, 3, 4};

    RGB rgb3(10);
    rgb3 += rgb3 + rgb1+rgb2;
    std::cout << rgb3 << std::endl << rgb1 << std::endl << rgb2;
}
```

I get `10 15 20` instead of `13 15 17` and I am stuck trying to find out the reason.
Thx in advance.

P.S. Sorry for all constexpr inline I was just testing out something locally.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah I've forgot to update that copy-pasted part, thanks)

Comment: You should really test the MCVE you give us, to make sure the problem is still reproducible.

Comment: What is `util`? Do you have your own functions in there?

Comment: Sorry all, that is my function, and that is not related to the questions, I've update the post and removed it.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efb9767261352324)

Comment: @NathanOliver I'll update the question with the exact code I have, no more abstraction of names

Comment: When the various operators `return result;` from a local variable of the base class, doesn't that slice?  Maybe I'm missing something, I don't do a lot of CRTP.

Comment: It was my impression that accessing/initializing derived class members before they've been constructed (in Base class Ctor), is UB. Maybe `RGB() : components{}, ColorModel() {}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your (main) issue is that you (non)-initialize `component` after base class (`ColorModel`) has set some values to it:

You might have consistent error with explicit initialization of component:

```
explicit RGB(const int& elem) : ColorModel(elem), component{} {}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffb1f4e8a2b7cdd7)

You might use [base from member idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member) to solve it.

```
struct Data
{
    std::array<int, 3> components{};
};

struct RGB : Data, ColorModel<0, int, RGB> {
// ...
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/459081c1918f44f3)

You also have issue with your `operator+`, as `ColorModel result;` is invalid (there are no derived class there), it should be `C result;` (same with return type).

Comment: I updated the code as you said with little changes, I'll post the answer soon, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

As @Jarod42 mentioned I needed to update the Base Color Space struct for my needs. I did the followings updates.

```
template<int S, typename T, typename C>
struct ColorModel {

    constexpr inline const T* cbegin() const {
        return static_cast<const C*>(this)->components.cbegin();
    }

    constexpr inline const T* cend() const {
        return static_cast<const C*>(this)->components.cend();
    }

    constexpr inline const T* begin() const {
        return cbegin();
    }

    constexpr inline const T* end() const {
        return cend();
    }

    constexpr inline T* begin() {
        return static_cast<C*>(this)->components.begin();
    }

    constexpr inline T* end() {
        return static_cast<C*>(this)->components.end();
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator=(const C& rhs) {
        std::copy(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), begin());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator=(C&& rhs) {
        std::move(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), begin());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator=(const T& rhs) {
        std::fill(begin(), end(), rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator=(T&& rhs) {
        std::fill(begin(), end(), rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator+=(const C& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::plus<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator+=(C&& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::plus<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator+=(const T& rhs) {
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, begin(), std::plus<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator+=(T&& rhs) {
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, begin(), std::plus<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator-=(const C& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::minus<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator-=(C&& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::minus<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator-=(const T& rhs) {
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, begin(), std::minus<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator-=(T&& rhs) {
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, begin(), std::minus<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator*=(const C& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator*=(C&& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator*=(const T& rhs) {
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator*=(T&& rhs) {
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator/=(const C& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::divides<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator/=(C&& rhs) {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(), std::divides<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator/=(const T& rhs) {
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, begin(), std::divides<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline ColorModel& operator/=(T&& rhs) {
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, begin(), std::divides<>());
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr inline C operator+(const C& rhs) const {
        C res;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), res.begin(), std::plus<>());
        return res;
    }

    constexpr inline C operator+(C&& rhs) const {
        C res;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), res.begin(), std::plus<>());
        return res;
    }

    constexpr inline C operator+(const T& rhs) const {
        C res;
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, res.begin(), std::plus<>());
        return res;
    }

    constexpr inline C operator+(T&& rhs) const {
        C res;
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, res.begin(), std::plus<>());
        return res;
    }

    constexpr inline C operator-(const C& rhs) const {
        C res;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), res.begin(), std::minus<>());
        return res;
    }

    constexpr inline C operator-(C&& rhs) const {
        C res;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), res.begin(), std::minus<>());
        return res;
    }

    constexpr inline C operator-(const T& rhs) const {
        C res;
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, res.begin(), std::minus<>());
        return res;
    }

    constexpr inline C operator-(T&& rhs) const {
        C res;
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, res.begin(), std::minus<>());
        return res;
    }

    constexpr inline C operator*(const C& rhs) const {
        C res;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), res.begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return res;
    }

    constexpr inline C operator*(C&& rhs) const {
        C res;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), res.begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return res;
    }

    constexpr inline C operator*(const T& rhs) const {
        C res;
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, res.begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return res;
    }

    constexpr inline C operator*(T&& rhs) const {
        C res;
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, res.begin(), std::multiplies<>());
        return res;
    }

    constexpr inline C operator/(const C& rhs) const {
        C res;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), res.begin(), std::divides<>());
        return res;
    }

    constexpr inline C operator/(C&& rhs) const {
        C res;
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), res.begin(), std::divides<>());
        return res;
    }

    constexpr inline C operator/(const T& rhs) const {
        C res;
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, res.begin(), std::divides<>());
        return res;
    }

    constexpr inline C operator/(T&& rhs) const {
        C res;
        util::transform(begin(), end(), rhs, res.begin(), std::divides<>());
        return res;
    }
};

template<int S, typename T, typename C>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ColorModel<S, T, C>& model) {
    std::for_each(model.begin(), model.end(), [&](const T& elem) { os << elem << " "; });
    return os;
}
```

As you see I *removed all constructors* from the *base class* as it is mainly for  **operators overloading** and let the child struct to initialize it's own fields with its own way. So my `struct RGB` was updated as follows

```
struct RGB : color_space::ColorModel<0, int, RGB> {
    std::array<int, 3> components{};

    RGB() = default;

    RGB(const std::initializer_list<int>& l){
        std::copy(l.begin(),l.end(),components.begin());
    }

    // All constructors you want

    using color_space::ColorModel<0, int, RGB>::operator=;
};
```

This resolved the issue of *not initializing my `std::array<int,3> components`*
Also I had to change the implementation of all operator overloads where **new** **instance** of **C(Child)** is created. And change the return-type accordingly.
Thanks.